# os.mkdir(linux_path) does not throw error when running in Windows

Tags: python, linux, windows, operating-system, mkdir

In a python snippet, i've os.mkdir(linux_path) and for testing purposes, i'm running the python code in Windows.

However, even when the linux path in windows is not available, the code is running and still not creating the path (as expected). But the code should throw some error since the code is trying to create a linux path in windows and still no error.

```
if not os.path.exists(<Linux_path>):
    os.makedirs(<Linux_path>)
```

could anyone please help on how to handle the exception/error situation here.

Thanks in Advance.
Arjun.

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: if not os.path.exists(<linux_path>):
        os.makedirs(<linux_path>)

I'm running this python snippet in windows command prompt for python. However no error is being thrown.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and put the code in **it** (and show the actually path).

Comment: How do you expect Windows to know that it is a "Linux path" and therefore shouldn't work? :-)  Most paths that are valid in Linux are *also* valid in Windows, although they may be interpreted differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In windows when you use `os.makedirs(r'\home\name\abc')` it will consider it as windows install directory path and create folder abc at `C:\home\name` and if you execute command `os.makedirs(r'home\name\abc')` this will create folder home in directory where your python script is running and it will create sub-folders within it(home - here).
Note: effect of command `os.makedirs(r'\home\name\abc')` and `os.makedirs(r'/home/name/abc')` will be the same. so you can use \ universally in your path.
It is helpful while working with cross-platform.

Comment: A Windows path that begins with a single slash or backslash is relative to the drive or UNC share of the current directory, not necessarily the C: drive.